# haproxy: explicitly setting the gpc0 value within a frontend or backend section

Tags: haproxy

I have something like this in my haproxy config

```
backend myservice
    option httplog
    stick-table type string size 10 expire 10m store gpc0
    stick store-request req.hdr(MYHDR)
    server server1 127.0.0.1:9494  check inter 1s rise 1 fall 1
```

I just used the above as an example. Since the stick table is indexed by a key; in this case it's the request header MYHDR. The gpc0 counter is capable of holding some value. I can set the value externally from the outside by using the UDS socket and socat.

```
set table name-of-the-table key <MYHDR> data.gpc0 <someval>
```

However, I can't figure out how to set the value of gpc0 from within the haproxy config.

What I have in mind is this:

For a request, use the stick-table as a general purpose hash table and store key=req.hdr(MYHDR), value=src (or some other stuff)

I'll use the value of the key later to make routing decisions for unrelated requests.

I couldn't figure out a way to use the stick-table in this manner. Is there something that  I missed? In any case, does it make sense to provide for a set-gpc0 method in the haproxy config? There are ways to increment and clear, but not set to a specific value.

I realize that the c in gpc stands for counter and I'm not exactly using it as a counter, but think of it as initializing a counter to a specific value instead of starting from 0.

Comment: I believe that this will give you the ability to get an absolute count and frequency of each distinct value for MYHDR in all requests that this backend processes, yes? I don't see where you are going with this, though.